# Как сделать такие же ссылки в словах на гитхабе в readme.md?

Tags: github, markdown

[image: Гитхаб гиперссылки]

Как сделать такие же ссылки в словах на гитхабе в readme.md? Увидел у другого человека и захотел сделать также

Comment: `[текст](ссылка)`

Comment: Спасибо, помог. Не ожидал что окажется так просто

Comment: Ознакомьтесь со статьёй про форматирование на GitHub - https://docs.github.com/ru/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax

Comment: Там точно где-то есть кнопка, позволяющая посмотреть исходный текст.